# Android databinding and viewmodel not working

Tags: android, data-binding, viewmodel, android-databinding

I have a ViewModel class, and a Model class in that.

```
class WorksheetViewModel {

    private Worksheet worksheet;

    public Worksheet getWorksheet() {
        return worksheet;
    }

    public void setWorksheet(Worksheet worksheet) {
        this.worksheet = worksheet;
        if (worksheet != null) showButtons();

        Logger.E(worksheet.getShort_text());
    }
```

**this is working here:  Logger.E(worksheet.getShort_text());**

and in my xml

```
<import type="android.view.View" />

<variable
    name="viewModel"
    type="viewmodels.WorksheetViewModel" />
```

..

and a textview with:

```
android:text="@{viewModel.worksheet.short_text + `?`}"
```

My probleme is, viewModel.worksheet.short_text is allways null. Why?

```
binding.setViewModel(new WorksheetViewModel());
binding.executePendingBindings();
```

Also I have all the

```
Worksheet extends BaseObservable
```

and

```
  @Bindable
    public String getShort_text() {
        return short_text;
    }
```

in my Worksheet

Comment: try android:text="@{viewModel.worksheet.getShort_text + `?`}"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is you are just setting ViewModel in binding `binding.setViewModel(new WorksheetViewModel());` but `WorksheerViewModel` also have `Worksheet` object, and it is blank.

So this should be

```
WorksheetViewModel viewModel = new WorksheetViewModel();
viewModel.setWorksheet(new WorkSheet('short text value'))
binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 2):

If any one get error in `binding.setViewmodel()`
it resolve by `binding.setViewmodel()`, In `setViewmodel`, `Viewmodel` is variable name which is given in layout.

e.g

```
<data>
     <variable
        name="userviewmodel"
        type="com.example.mvvmtest.viewmodel.LoginViewModel" />
</data>
```

Than use, `binding.setUserviewmodel()`